Excel VBA Type mismatch error with Evaluate
I have a For loop to examine whether there are any remainder when I divide the row numbers of column A by 10. For this purpose, I use the MOD function and define a variable by the applying Evaluate.
If the result of this variable zero, the code should do additional tasks which are OK.
My problem is when the routine enters the IF statement, I receive a Run time error 13: Type mismatch.
Could you please help me why?
Here is my code:
Sub copcol()

Dim nmr As Variant

Sheets(1).Activate

lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lrow

nmr = Evaluate("=MOD(ROW(A" & i & "),10)")

If nmr = 0 Then
'Do something


Why not just IF i mod 10 = 0 Then?  or better yet Let i = 10 to lrow step 10?

Just to clarify: how to incorporate IsNumeric into the code?

IF i mod 10 = 0 Then is good idea, thank you.

(1) The reason for the type mismatch is a little bit surprising: The formula will return an array with one element, and you can't check the value of a whole array. Two ways to fix that:

make a single value formula by putting a @ in front of the formula:
Evaluate("=@MOD(ROW(A" & i & "),10)")
Leave the formula as it is but use an index into the result:
If nmr(1) = 0 Then

(2) Both variants are much too complicated. There is no reason to use the Row-function when we have the number already in i. The following statement is already a little bit easier:
nmr = Evaluate("=@MOD(" & i & ",10)")

(3) There is no reason to use the Evaluate-function to call the Excel version of MOD. Use the native VBA mod function Mod instead:
nmr = i Mod 10

There is hardly any reason to use Evaluate in VBA except maybe if you need complex mathematic formulas. Personally, I cannot remember using Evaluate more that maybe a handful times in my whole VBA career. Evaluate makes the code much slower and opens the door to hard to find errors.
(4) If you really want to do something only on every 10th row, you can specify this already in your For-loop (Scott Craner suggested this in the comments:)
For i = 10 to lrow step 10
   (...)
Next i


What a complete answer!

A one-element array: ... you always discover something unexpected in VBA +:) - Side note: this counts here only in case (1) as the evaluation is range related.

@T.M. It's not VBA-related, it's Excel feature.

@rotabor Sorry, range-related Excel translated into VBA evidence :-;

Many thanks for your detailed answer and explanations.
